# Running a PHP script when client close

Tags: php

Is it possible to run a PHP script when the client is closing?

I want to send data to SQL when the user exits the site.
Is this possible to do or do i have to find another way a round this?

Comment: You need to use ajax/ javascript on close action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reliable way - and can't be, as per how HTTP works. The error prone and unreliable ways (like setting up a companion websocket connection and acting when it closes or heavy polling) are *very* hard to build in PHP and would require special setup - since normally PHP scripts only run on requests (and there is no request when user exits site).